# Blender cannot show mesh properly in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

This behavior is so bizarre that I can't explain it in just a few sentences.
When I start up blender (version is 2.81) as always, there is cube in the middle, only that my cube isn't visible, there is just outline. In material preview and render mode, cube is visible but black (probably because of materials). When I deselect the cube, not even outline is visible.
[image]

When adding another object, that object becomes like mirage of previous object. On its place there is non-clickable solid that looks like previous object.

EXAMPLE:
after startup, torus is added above the cube. There is outlined torus, but cube is visible instead of torus. If another object is added, it will be torus and so on. This happens only with meshes (not curves, metaballs etc.).
[image]

When I render the image, everything looks how it should be, problem is only in viewport.

My specs:

Blender 2.81.16

Windows 10 Pro

Processor: Intel i5 2.30 GHz

8 GB RAM

Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6470M, latest driver installed

Comment: There could be a few things going on. I know I've seen some users have issues with older AMD cards (though I think the one from the example I read was an HD 5760 or somthing like that). Also , there have been issues with graphics drivers needing updating. There is a post of what you are talking about from back in 2018, but it doesn't seem to have a satisfactory resolution. Link is here if you want to check it out - https://blenderartists.org/t/object-always-see-through/1115094. However, based on the other post I read (i'll link if I find it), you may want to think about upgrading your GPU.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks, it was graphic card related. Apparently I needed a new driver. I previously quickly checked if latest drivers were installed, and internet and device manager said yes. But I was kinda desperate and searched for other drivers. Found it, now it works like a charm.